# Google Tag Manager, Data Layer across pageviews

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I assume many websites now have the following use case, which is to set whether a user has consented or not to analytics & tracking.

The `dataLayer` variables seem a perfect place to store this information - however they are present only on each pageview.

How are people implementing cross page view `dataLayer` variables?

Should we be setting more cookies?

Comment: Please explain why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a cookie and the read it on each page to manage setting in GTM.